# How to "call" a JavaScript file that changes theme color from light to dark

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-theme, dark-theme

I have a dark theme code that works perfectly on localhost. As soon as I replicate it online in WordPress; the theme-switch toggles from dark to light but no changes take effect.

**test.html**

```
<div class="my-class">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-it" id="toggle-theme">
</div>
```

**functions.php**

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
  $parent_style = 'parent-style';
  wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
  wp_enqueue_style('dark-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dark-theme.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

function enqueue_theme_switcher_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('my-switcher', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jswitcher.js', array(), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_switcher_script');
```

**dark-theme.css**

```
body.dark-theme {
    background-color: #1d1d1d !important;
}
/* more css etc... */
```

**jswitcher.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById("toggle-theme");
    const body = document.body;

    themeToggle.addEventListener("change", function () {
        body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
        updateThemeCookie();
    });
/* more scripts etc... */
```

I have checked all paths, ID etc. I searched here but nothing about actually calling the function within the main menu top bar as oppose to calling it via an HTML/PHP document. The HTML in test.html is pasted within a custom HTML 'widget' within Max Mega Menu In WordPress.

Comment: your dark-theme is commented off. Instead of putting filenames inside the codeblock, put that before the code block (e.g. "my dark-theme.css looks like:") and then show the code you're using (in [mcve] form). That way, you don't accidentally comment things out, and folks can see what real code you're using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @ Mike. I appreciate the heads up. I'm new here and learning. My apologies for any confusion in my post above.

Comment: I have edited the post above to make it clearer to distinguish between all the separate file types.

Comment: Let's gather some more debug info to understand what's happening. Perhaps the widget doesn't exist yet at the time the script is loaded? (You can set a breakpoint to check.)Or it exists more than once (and then only the first instance gets the event listener attached)? Are there any errors in the browser console? Is there a change listener attached to the switch (according to browser devtools)? Does manually adding the body class through devtools change the background color as expected? Does manually executing the contents of the JS file in the browser console make the switch work temporarily?

Comment: @CheeryDT I changed loading order of script this evening after reaching home late yesterday reflecting your suggestions but nothing changed. I forgot to mention that my dark them loads even if my OS and browser is set to light theme, cache cleared and restart. I want to post my full jswitcher.js script but the comments don't allow the embedding of code as in my previous post.